# Slow VBA loop ( copying some arrays in one array)

Tags: excel, vba, performance, loops

I have a very simple work to do :
I have 4 (much more in reality) important arrays and i need to sum them to have one final array.
I can do it in excel formula without VBA, the calculation is less than one second but the file is too big.
So i tried to do it with VBA but all my loops are very slow and I don't manage to improve them.
I hope that somebody will be able to improve my loop ( or to find an alternative solution like to sum 2 arrays directly)

Thank you!!

My last version was this one :
( file is in manual calculation)

```
Sub Loprange()
 
k = 0
Dim imax As Integer
Dim jmax As Integer


imax = Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(Range(Range("pose"), Range("pose").End(xlToRight))) - 1
jmax = Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(Range(Range("pose"), Range("pose").End(xlDown))) - 1

Dim myarray(0 To 4418, 0 To 44) As Variant


For i = 0 To 4418
For j = 0 To 44

myarray(i, j) = myarray(i, j) + Worksheets("AAAA").Range("U3").Offset(i, j).Value
Next j
Next i

i = 0
j = 0
For i = 0 To 4418
For j = 0 To 44

myarray(i, j) = myarray(i, j) + Worksheets("BBBB").Range("U3").Offset(i, j).Value
Next j
Next i

i = 0
j = 0
For i = 0 To 4418
For j = 0 To 44

myarray(i, j) = myarray(i, j) + Worksheets("CCCC").Range("U3").Offset(i, j).Value
Next j
Next i

i = 0
j = 0
For i = 0 To 4418
For j = 0 To 44

myarray(i, j) = myarray(i, j) + Worksheets("DDDD").Range("U3").Offset(i, j).Value
Next j
Next i


Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("U3:BN4421") = myarray
End Sub
```

but it is too slow ( i tried also on double loop with

```
myarray(i, j) = myarray(i, j) + Worksheets("AAAA").Range("U3").Offset(i, j).Value+ Worksheets("BBBB").Range("U3").Offset(i, j).Value+Worksheets("CCCC").Range("U3").Offset(i, j).Value+Worksheets("DDDD").Range("U3").Offset(i, j).Value
```

but it almost the same time and too slow.

I wanted to try the MMULT solution but my arrays could be empty and the calculation cannot be done if a cell is blanck ( instead of 0)

Comment: It's slow because you're accessing a range inside the loop.  Don't do that.  Instead,  copy that range to another array outside the loop, then access the array in the loop

Comment: On which sheet is `"pose"` located and is it `U3`? Is this code in the same workbook as the sheets?

Answer (score 0):

What makes VBA slow, is when interactions with the worksheet happen many times.
In your case, you are doing 3 x 4418 x 44 + 1 (= 583,177) worksheet interactions; And I assume the intent is to do even more (?)

A better way I found is load the values of the entire table into a single array with one interaction:

```vb
Dim ws as Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("AAAA")

' Read data into Array
Dim dataFromSheet as Variant ' Important: has to be type Variant. 
Set dataFromSheet = ws.Range(ws.Range("U3"), ws.Range("U3").Offset(4418,44)).Value ' .Value or .Value2, as needed
```

ONe things to note here: The variable (`dataFromSheet` in this demonstration) has to be declared as type Variant, and not an array of type variant. It will behave as a 2-dimensional array anyway.

After you are done, you can save back the entire array into the worksheet:

```vb
ws.Range(ws.Range("U3"), ws.Range("U3").Offset(4418,44)).Value = dataFromSheet
```

This way, you'd reduce your worksheet interactions from 583,177 down to 4. This should speed up your code immensely.

Note: You can also write back a larger amount of data, then you'd need to use the `.Resize(..)` function on the target range.

Answer (score 0):

You can optimize your code by using a Variant array to store the values from your worksheet, which is generally faster than directly reading and writing cell values in a loop. Another option is to use the Application.ScreenUpdating and Application.Calculation properties to temporarily disable screen updates and automatic calculations, which can significantly speed up the execution of your code. Here is an example of using those techniques:

```
Sub Loprange2()
    
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim imax As Long, jmax As Long
    Dim myarray() As Variant
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    ' Turn off screen updating and calculation for speed
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    ' Define the dimensions of your array
    imax = 4418
    jmax = 44

    ' Initialize your result array
    ReDim myarray(0 To imax, 0 To jmax)

    ' Loop through worksheets and add values to the result array
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("AAAA", "BBBB", "CCCC", "DDDD"))
        For i = 0 To imax
            For j = 0 To jmax
                myarray(i, j) = myarray(i, j) + ws.Cells(3 + i, 21 + j).Value
            Next j
        Next i
    Next ws

    ' Write the result array to Sheet1
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("U3").Resize(imax + 1, jmax + 1).Value = myarray

    ' Turn screen updating and calculation back on
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    
End Sub
```

Comment: In my PC the updated version takes 1.984 seconds. It was 11.820 seconds on the original code.
By the way, I think the range of the final write destination in your code must be:
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("U3:BM4421") = myarray

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help. I finally used an array of array and it less than 2 seconds for 30 sheets at the moment. Here is the code I used:

```
Sub arrayrange()
        
    k = 1
    Dim imax As Integer
    Dim jmax As Integer
        
    imax = Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(Range(Range("pose"), Range("pose").End(xlToRight))) - 1
    jmax = Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(Range(Range("pose"), Range("pose").End(xlDown))) - 1
    
    Dim myarray(1 To 4419, 1 To 46) As Variant
    Dim name() As Variant
    Dim Weight() As Variant
    Dim arrayofarray() As Variant    
    
    name = Range(Range("onlget"), Range("onlget").End(xlDown))
    arrayofarray() = Range(Range("onlget"), Range("onlget").End(xlDown))
    
    nameleng = UBound(name) - LBound(name) + 1
        
    For k = 1 To nameleng
    
    arrayofarray(k, 1) = Worksheets(name(k, 1)).Range("U3:BN4421").Value
    Next k
    k = 1
    For i = 1 To 4419
    For j = 1 To 46
    For k = 1 To nameleng
    myarray(i, j) = myarray(i, j) + arrayofarray(k, 1)(i, j) 
    Next k
    k = 1
    Next j
    Next i
        
    Worksheets("Recap").Range("AO3:CH4421") = myarray
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the next way

```
Sub Loprange()
  Dim ws As Worksheet, arrFin, arrSh, arrSheets, lastR As Long, lastCol As Long, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
  
  arrSheets = Array(Worksheets("AAAA"), Worksheets("BBBB"), Worksheets("CCCC"), Worksheets("DDDD"))

  Set ws = ActiveSheet
  lastR = ws.cells(ws.rows.count, ws.Range("pose").column).End(xlUp).Row 'lastRow
  lastCol = ws.cells(ws.Range("pose").Row, ws.Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).column 'last column
  
  'input each used sheet in an array:
  ReDim arrSh(UBound(arrSheets))
  For i = 0 To UBound(arrSheets)
    arrSh(i) = arrSheets(i).Range("U3").Resize(lastR, lastCol).Value2
  Next i
  'redim the finallArray
  ReDim arrFin(1 To lastR - ws.Range("pose").Row + 1, 1 To lastCol - ws.Range("pose").column + 1)
  
  'add the array elements in only one iteration:
  For i = 1 To UBound(arrFin)
    For j = 1 To UBound(arrFin, 2)
        For k = 0 To UBound(arrSh)
            arrFin(i, j) = arrFin(i, j) + arrSh(k)(i, j)
        Next k
    Next j
  Next i
  
  'drop the final array result in the necessary sheet:
  Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("U3").Resize(UBound(arrFin), UBound(arrFin, 2)).Value2 = arrFin
End Sub
```

Please, test it and send some feedback. Supposing that I correctly understood your question, it should be very fast working mostly in memory. I assumed that `pose` is a named range **of a cell**...